# Google Contact API - 401 Client Error, while using OAuth 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-contacts-api

I am successfully logged in Google plus using Google Plus API, and able to fetch friends details. But when i am trying to list All contacts mail id, I'm getting the 401 error in request. But I am doing Oauth_2.0 Authentication to sign in.

Please suggest me, where m i making mistake in fetching emails list using Contact API.

My Code --->

```
    auth.clientID     = @"XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    auth.clientSecret =@"XXXXXXX-rBvkLjV1DUIJ4";

    NSString *urlStr =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"https:www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    NSLog(@"--url_string---->%@",urlStr);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Gdata-version"];

    auth.scope= @"https:www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";        
    [auth authorizeRequest:request
                  completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    NSString *output = nil;

     if (error) {
         output = [error description];
       } else {
           NSURLResponse *response = nil;
           NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request                                                          returningResponse:&response                                                                      error:&error];
       if (data) {
 //API fetch succeed here
        output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"\n\noutput--->%@", output);
         } else {
 //fetch failed
         output = [error description];
                 }
             }
         }];
```

Error in Log Response is ---->

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Error
401
(Client Error)!!1</title>
<style type="text/css">
        *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKsAAADVC> #g{margin-left:-2px}#g img{visibility:hidden}* html #g img{visibility:visible}*+html #g img{visibility:visible}
      </style></head>
<body><a href="//www.google.com/" id="g"><img src="//www.google.com/images/logo_sm_2.gif" alt="Google" width="150" height="55"></a>
```

**401.**
That's an error.

There was an error in your request.
That's all we know.

Comment: I suppose that you must have a Google API console app for the accounts usage, did you check your permissions in Google API console ? I think  `Contacts API`  must be enabled for this request to work.

Comment: @danypata i checked it, Contact API is enabled in Google API Console.

Comment: 401 error is thrown generally when access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

Comment: @SGC than how could i make request successfull, could u answer my question

Comment: @Imran refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors